# moment.js 2 digit year converting wrong 4 digit year

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Has anyone come across this issue with Moment.js: In Firefox using moment("6/12/15").format("M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss A") I get 6/12/1915 instead of 6/12/2015?

Comment: If I go to the momentjs.com site and paste that into the console, I get 2015 (and a deprecation notice).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I get 1915 in Firefox. Simple fix, don't use a 2 digit year.

Comment: you can override the moment.parseTwoDigitYear method to set your own custom window, for example see here:  https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2219

Comment: @Jack: Sure enough, happens in Firefox and not Chrome. And this is why there's a deprecation notice. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you throw a random string into `moment` without telling it what format it's in, it falls back on the JavaScript `Date` object for parsing, and the format you're passing in is not defined by the standard. That leaves you wide open to implementation-specific behavior. In this case, what you describe happens on Firefox but not on Chrome.

This has been a sufficient issue that Moment is [deprecating it entirely](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407).

To get reliable results with that string, tell Moment what format it's in:

```
moment("6/12/15", "M/D/YY").format("M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss A")
```

Comment: Will do. I appreciate the explanation all the overrides weren't working for me. So I will make sure the user cannot pass in a 2 digit year because I need a 4 digit year for the DB. Thank you!